# how to find the right path for A* algorithm (not the real time algorithm)

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Hey to everyone I am trying to understand A* algorithm not the real time A* algorithm
To understand this I created the following problem

- Node s is connected with Α and the heuristic value of Α is 4  with
  travel cost 2
- Node s is connected with Β and heuristic value of Β is    4  with
  travel cost 3
- Node Α is connected with C and heuristic value    of C is 4  with
  travel cost 3
- Node B is connected with C and heuristic value of C is 4  with travel
  cost 1
- Node B is connected with D and heuristic value of D is 3.5 with
  travel cost 3
- Node C is connected with D and heuristic value of D is 3.5 with
  travel cost 1
- Node C is connected with E and heuristic value of E is 1  with travel
  cost 3
- Node D is connected with F and heuristic value of F είναι 2    with
  travel cost 2
- Node E is connected with G and heuristic value of    G είναι 0  with
  travel cost 2
- Node F is connected with G and    heuristic value of G είναι 0  with
  travel cost 1

The goal is G

the following tree is :

https://imgur.com/a/qYHHLK9

my solution :

https://imgur.com/a/y2gIBD2

My question is the following the path will include everything I visited  S-> A->B->C->E->G or S->B->C->E->G